# É possível saber as funções de uma DLL sem ter a sua documentação?

Tags: funções, dll

É possível descobrirmos quais funções estão disponíveis em uma DLL sem ter a sua documentação em mãos para podermos utilizar, em Java, por exemplo?

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar: http://www.dependencywalker.com/. Aliás, essa pergunta tem mais referencias: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438900/how-to-view-dll-functions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É possível obter essas informações através de um utilitário para listar os membros da DLL, como o [dumpbin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=vs-2019) do Visual Studio ou o [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) ou o [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Não dará muitos detalhes e não dirá quais realmente podem ser usadas livremente. Listará até mesmo o que é privado e não deveria ser chamado. Portanto se atenha à documentação. Sempre! Se não está documentado não use.

O fato de achar funções na DLL não significa de forma alguma que poderá usá-las diretamente no Java, muito menos se não souber exatamente como usar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Reforçando *Se não está documentado, não use.*. +1