# Como descobrir o nome das funções de uma DLL?

Tags: delphi, dll, descompilação

já utilizei o *DLL Export*, *Dependency Walker*, *dumpbin*, *PE Explorer* e o resultado para várias DLLs que preciso utilizar é sempre o mesmo com duas funções: `CLRRP` e `GETRP`.... sem parâmetros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que a biblioteca foi desenvolvida em Delphi, pois renomeando a extensão da DLL para EXE aparece o ícone do Delphi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você não conseguiu "ver" os métodos com o DLL Export.. provavelmente não foi marcado como exported na compilação.. você pretende fazer um "hook" dos métodos? Ou chamar os métodos de uma outra aplicação?

Comment: Eu acho que não tem um problema específico aí, no geral você já sabe e seria isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113284/101

Comment: bigown, como eu disse acima, eu já tinha feito tudo o que esse link indicou, mas o resultado foi o mesmo....duas funções e sem resultados para uso.

Answer (score 4):

O correto é você fazer a importação da DLL como componente para o Delphi, e não sair fazendo engenharia reversa nas DLL (questão pessoal de ética).

Menu: `Component -> Import Component...`

Dessa forma o Delphi criara uma `unit` com as `funções` e `procedures` que possuem na biblioteca!

Como você ja fez o teste trocando a extensão da DLL para EXE e obteve o ícone da IDE do Delphi então não acredito que a Biblioteca seja *ActiveX*, então na hora de importar o componente escolha a opção: `Import a Type Library`.

Se a DLL não aparecer na Lista de Bibliotecas disponíveis no momento da importação você deve registrar essa DLL para que o Delphi a reconheça:

```
regsvr32 "caminho_da_dll"
```

Comment: Grato Júnior, o problema é que a empresa que fez essas bibliotecas largou o sistema em uma empresa e se recusa a dar informações, por isso tenho que descobrir e não importa o método. Eu uso o Delphi 7 e tem várias bibliotecas que o ícone é do Delphi 7.....você poderia explicar como você faz isso nessa versão?

Comment: Quando eu conheci o Delphi já foi na versão XE2, porém o método de importação de componente deve ser o mesmo, mudando apenas nome de Menus (Programei em Delphi 5 e não conheço o Delphi 7).